# Proof via Taylor Expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion, exponential-function

The following is claimed:

Show: $e^x \ge 1 + x + x^2/2 \qquad    \forall   x \ge 0   $

Proof:

Taylor expansion via Maclaurin:

$ e^x = f(0) + f'(0)(x-0) + f''(0)(x-0)^2$/2 + $\int_0^x (x-t)^2f'''(t)/2\,dt $

I see how they're trying to prove the claim, but I don't understand the last integral part as it related to the Taylor series and higher order differentials of f(x) about f(0).

Is this expansion stating the upper bound of the higher order differentials ($\ge 3$) is bounded by the integral, and if so, shouldn't the integral be divided by $6$ as in the usual Taylor series?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Derivation_for_the_integral_form_of_the_remainder.

Comment: Why not integrate by parts the last term and see what happens?